# dvdauthor documentation?

Tags: documentation, dvdauthor

Where is the rest of the dvdauthor documentation? If you [read it](http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/doc/dvdauthor.html), many functions and attributes have no descriptions (like commandline options or XML tags.) Other programs, however, use those tags. Has someone written a guide that fills in the gaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link seems to be extending the man page/homepage documentation http://nfs.shawnfumo.com/wiki/DVDAuthor/XML